# Passing a model property to a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having trouble passing the correct data to a partial view, and I'm not sure why it is failing.

Say I have models

```
public class SubModel {
  public string Wobble {get; set;}
}

public class MyModel {
  public SubModel Wibble {get; set;}
}
```

and views

```
MyView.cshtml

@model MyModel

@Html.Partial("SomePartial", Model.Wibble)
```

and

```
SomePartial.cshtml

@model SubModel

<h1>Victory!</h1>
```

this fails with `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MyModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MySubModel'`

When I change `MyView.cshtml` to

```
@model MyModel

@Html.Partial("SomePartial", Model.Wibble, new ViewDataDictionary<MySubModel>(Model.Wibble))
```

It works as expected.

Why do I need to explicitly pass a `ViewDataDictionary`? Why can't I just pass the model?

Note: I'm using a library that does things that make me go hrm? a lot of the time. If the above behaviour is not expected, it might be this libraries fault.

Answer (score 8):

This happens when the model you pass to the partial view is `null`. Don't pass null to a partial view, or it will get confused about its type.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try passing the submodel with `Model.Wibble` instead of `MyModel.Wibble`? The associated model is accessible in a view with Model, not the model's name.

Comment: It was a typo, I fixed the question